# Decimal(5, 1) MySql Data Type

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-5

In one of tables I am using a Data Type of `decimal(5,1)`.  I have looked at this [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html).  It specifically says **D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.**

So, the property in my table that is of type `decimal(5,1)` is auto-filled at *0.00* on my *Create* page in my web application.  How are the two '0's possible if it should only allow 1 digit to the right of the decimal point?

Comment: is it stored as a decimal(5,1) but when the web application gets it it's converted to a decimal, which has whatever a decimal has in c#? and the web frontend is just displaying a decimal with two digits after the .?

Comment: This seems like a problem in your C# code, not MySQL. Is it reading the schema and paying attention to the precision? Can you post the associated view code that's problematic?

Comment: As @JohnBoker says, this is more of an issue how the C# side of your code formats the `decimal` type than how it's stored in the database.  The default formatting in C# for `decimal` depends on your Culture settings, but usually has two decimal places.

Comment: @tadman I figured it out. see my answer. it was indeed my c#

Comment: @jmoerdyk I figured it out. see my answer. it was indeed my c#

Comment: @JohnBoker I figured it out. see my answer. it was indeed my c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the answer, in my Model I need to do:

```
[Display(Name = "Total:")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] /*Part I needed*/
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required!")]
public decimal Total { get; set; }
```